# Storing an exception as a variable

Tags: c#, variables, exception, asynchronous, var

I'm having an issue where exceptions are handled through another code library. Does anyone know if it's possible to store an exception as a variable so you can call it?

I'm a bit new to C#, but I was under the impression that you can store anything in the var. I need to pass it because I'm throwing an exception in an async thread and I need to move it back to the main thread which handles the exceptions. I can't pass it because an async class can only be a Task or Void. Any ideas how I could get something like this to work?

```
var passedException = Exception(123456,"Bad thing that happened");
throw new passedException;
```

Comment: If you're using a `Task` then an [`AggregateException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx) will be thrown when you try to get the result or wait for the task to complete.

Answer (score 1):

You should look more closely into what the `var` data type actually is, it has nothing to with your code not working.

Here are some problems with it; you try to call the `Exception` constructor without using the `new` keyword. On the next line you try to use the `new` keyword on an instance when it only applies to types.

```
 Exception e = new Exception("My custom message!");
 throw e;
```

works just fine.

If you want to use `var` then you can do `var e` but it has no value here and imo is just an abuse of the feature. `var` is just syntactic sugar, the compiler will only allow it if the type can be inferred from the right hand side of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
var passedException = new Exception(123456,"Bad thing that happened");
throw passedException;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `new` keyword to the first line where you're creating the `Exception` object:

```
var passedException = new Exception(123456,"Bad thing that happened");
throw passedException;
```